# Can't keep an SSE connection open in Spring

Tags: java, spring, server-sent-events

I've been trying to send real-time messages to an http client using SSEs using the following class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter;

@RestController
public class SSETestController {
    private List<SseEmitter> sseEmitters = new ArrayList<>();

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public SseEmitter eventEmitter() throws IOException {
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    sseEmitters.add(sseEmitter);
    return sseEmitter;
    }
}
```

and the html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        const eventSource = new EventSource("/message");
        eventSource.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
            const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(message);
        });

        eventSource.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("error");
        }

        eventSource.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
        console.log('connection is live');
        });


    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I load the page I get the following error on Firefox' console : `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at http://localhost:8080/message.` I've also tried it with different browsers but I get similar results.

Nearly all the tutorials I followed use this method to establish an SSE connection but I somehow cannot seem to get it to work, is there maybe something I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

I've tried doing `sseEmitter.complete()` before returning the emitter but it just causes the connection to be succesful briefly and then it breaks down again. Then the client tries to reconnect to the server.

Comment: What's the http error code you are seeing in the browser? Are you seeing any errors in the server logs? If not, try increasing the logging verbosity in the server and seeing what's happening there.